# Escape quotes in jq

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I've the following two bash lines

```
TMPFILE="$(mktemp)" || exit 1

< package.json jq '. + {"foo":'"${BOO}"'}' > "$TMPFILE"
```

but I get the following error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
. + {"foo":}
jq: 1 compile error
```

any idea how to escape properly that part by having the double quote there to mute the shellcheck error

Comment: what's the content of variable BOO? - ok it's empty so syntax error, because there are no quote inside jq command (quotes are syntactical for bash in this command except quotes around foo)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just use a variable and save yourself the hassle:

```
< package.json jq --arg b "$BOO" '. + { foo: $b }'
```

`--arg b "$BOO"` creates a variable `$b` that you can use inside `jq`, without having to deal with quoting issues.

That said, the reason that your attempt was failing was that you were missing some literal double quotes:

```
< package.json jq '. + { foo: "'"$BOO"'" }'
```

The extra double quotes *inside* each of the the single-quoted parts of the command are needed, as the other ones are consumed by the shell before the command string is passed to `jq`.

This will still fail in the case that the shell variable contains any quotes, so the first approach is the preferred one.